# Why care about ultrafilters (in operator algebras)?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-algebras, filters

I recently learned about filters and ultrafilters and the notion of convergence with respect to an ultrafilter in a topological space. I have to say, at first I could not appreciate their potential. I think the two central theorems are the following:

> Proposition: Let $X$ be a set. Then any $S\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ having the finite intersection property is included in some ultrafilter.

> Proposition: Let $X$ be a topological space. Then $X$ is compact if-f every ultrafilter converges to at least one point in $X$. Also, $X$ is Hausdorff if-f every ultrafilter converges at most to one point in $X$.

I realized that ultrafilters are a powerful tool when I saw a very simple proof of Tychonoff's theorem using ultrafilters. I always thought that Tychonoff's theorem had a difficult proof and I was amazed to see such a simple proof using ultrafilters.

I would like to ask the following question: how are ultrafilters used in operator algebras? What are some interesting/ standard applications they have in this field? What books or papers would you recommend to someone that wants to understand the use of ultrafilters in operator algebras?

Bonus question: What about topology, in general? To what cause would someone use ultrafilters besides proving that a space is compact or Hausdorff? Are there any interesting constructions based on ultrafilters?

Comment: Try searching for ultra products.  This is related to one of the most recent breakthroughs in operator algebras: the Connes embedding problem.

Comment: The ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with elements of $\beta\mathbb{N}$, or to phrase it in more operator algebraic terms, characters of $\ell_\infty$. But this also means you don't really need ultrafilters for ultraproduct constructions if you prefer these other descriptions.

Comment: @Ruy are you referring to the proof from complexity theory? Could you elaborate on how ultraproducts are related?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I don't think ultraproducts are used in the the proof, but the original formulation of the Connes embedding problem asked whether every separable II$_1$-factor can be embedded into an ultrapower of the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor (or, equivalently, an ultraproduct of matrix algebras).

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, I agree. So, in a sense, since the Connes embedding conjecture was answered negatively, this recent breakthrough can be seen as somewhat reducing the allure of ultraproducts.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Maybe somewhat, but ultraproducts are still really useful. I just don't think they are a good argument for the usefulness of ultrafilters, because they can just as conveniently be defined in terms of the equivalent characterizations from my first comment.

Comment: Yes, but the other descriptions are just as non-constructive. I have an aversion to non-constructive things, particularly in applied contexts.

Comment: @Ittay, I think MaoWao has already answered your question but I could try to be more specific if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

The use of ultrafilters in topology is extremely well established. Bourbaki would be a standard reference. Filters in general are fundamental tools in set theory and analysis, albeit not so common in the standard pedagogical route. One can even construct the real numbers in terms of filters of rational numbers.

As you point out, ultrafilters are a convenient tool when proving various results. It is a way avoid the cumbersome details of sequences and nets (when sequences are not enough). The set-theoretic formalism of filters encapsulates things quite nicely. However, of course, ultrafilters are highly non-constructive. You will never see one that is not principal. So, their use is only theoretical.

Ultrafilters are very cool, no doubt. However, one should be aware of other cool options to prove results, e.g., Tychonoff's theorem, without ultrafilters. For instance, the characterisation of compactness in terms of the closedness of the projection mapping with respect to all spaces leads to a beautiful proof of Tychonoff's theorem [Tychonoff’s theorem in a category, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.]. That proof is applicable in a much wider context than the ultrafilter proof since it is not set-theoretic based.

I hope this somewhat answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate this. I am leaving this unaccepted because I would like to see some more answers with a more operator algebraic orientation, but this sure gives me some information for the more general topological setting

Answer (score 2):

Here is an application of ultra-filters that is very much in the spirit
of operator algebras.  The ultra-filters in question are not quite on
topological spaces, but instead, in the context of [meet
semi-lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice).

For example, if   $X$ is a topological space, then the set of all subsets
of $X$,  denoted $\mathscr P(X)$, is a meet semi-lattice relative to the
order of inclusion and the usual ultra-filters  in $X$ correspond
precisely to ultra-filters in the meet semi-lattice $\mathscr P(X)$.

With these disclaimers, here we go:  many fundamental examples of
C$^*$-algebras  possess a set $S$ of generators consisting of [partial
isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry).   Moreover the set $S$ is often closed under
multiplication and adjoint, in which case it forms an [inverse
semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup).

Since the algebraic structure of inverse semigroups is way easier to
understand as  compared to C$^*$-algebras, the question arises as to what
extent the given C$^*$-algebra may be reconstructed entirely in terms of
the generating  inverse semigroup $S$.

As it turns out the answer is generally negative because one can easily
obtain examples of non-isomorphic C$^*$-algebras generated by isomorphic
inverse semigroups of partial isometries.

Nevertheless, there is a construction of a specific C$^*$-algebra from
any given
inverse semigroup $S$, called the tight C$^*$-algebra, which is able to
recover some of the most important C$^*$-algebra in applications, such as
Cuntz-algebras and a host of other examples.

The contruction of the tight C$^*$-algebra can be made from a certain
dynamical system on the closure of the space of all **ultra-filters** of the
idempotent semi-lattice of the given inverse semigroup.

Comment: Thanks for the information!